# Merge pandas df based on 2 keys

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 df and I would like to merge them based on 2 keys - ID and date:
I following is just a small slice of the entire df

**df_pw6**

```
     ID     date           pw10_0        pw50_0     pw90_0
0   153     2018-01-08     27.88590     43.2872     58.2024
0   2       2018-01-05     11.03610     21.4879     31.6997
0   506     2018-01-08     6.98468      25.3899     45.9486
```

**df_ex**

```
    date         ID   measure f188  f187  f186  f185
0   2017-07-03  501     NaN     1   0.5     7   4.0
1   2017-07-03  502     NaN     0   2.5     5   3.0
2   2018-01-08  506     NaN     5   9.0     9   1.2
```

As you can see, only the third row has a match. 
When I type:

```
#check date
df_ex.iloc[2,0]== df_pw6.iloc[1,1]
True

#check ID
df_ex.iloc[2,1] == df_pw6.iloc[2,0]
True
```

Now I try to merge them:

```
df19 = pd.merge(df_pw6,df_ex,on=['date','ID'])
```

I get an empty df

When I try:

```
df19 = pd.merge(df_pw6,df_ex,how ='left',on=['date','ID'])
```

I get:

```
    ID     date                  pw10_0     pw50_0     pw90_0   measure     f188    f187    f186    f185
0   153 2018-01-08 00:00:00     27.88590    43.2872     58.2024     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   2   2018-01-05 00:00:00     11.03610    21.4879     31.6997     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   506 2018-01-08 00:00:00     6.98468     25.3899     45.9486     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

My desired result should be:

```
>      ID     date                    pw10_0       pw50_0     pw90_0   measure f188  f187  f186  f185
> 
> 0   506     2018-01-08 00:00:00     6.98468     25.3899     45.9486   NaN     5     9.0     9   1.2
```

Comment: The `left ` join is working correctly, the date value for ID 506 is 2018-01-08 in df_pw6 whereas 2018-01-05 in df_ex so there are no common rows by these two ids

Comment: @GauravTaneja You mean the `inner` merge. Although the `left` merge is also working as expected. OP, your two DataFrames have **no** matching keys in this example.

Comment: as above comment suggested, you don't have a match in the example. could you edit your question so we know what you real problem is ?

Comment: I edited my question, now there is a match (last row),thanks

Comment: I actually cannot replicate your result that getting a empty df with `df19 = pd.merge(df_pw6,df_ex,on=['date','ID'])`

Answer (score 0):

I have run your codes post your edit, and I succeeded in getting the desired result.

```
import pandas as pd

# copy paste your first df by hand
pw = pd.read_clipboard()

# copy paste your second df by hand
ex = pd.read_clipboard()

pd.merge(pw,ex,on=['date','ID'])
# output [edited. now it is the correct result OP wanted.]

    ID        date   pw10_0   pw50_0   pw90_0  measure  f188  f187  f186  f185
0  506  2018-01-08  6.98468  25.3899  45.9486      NaN     5   9.0     9   1.2
```

Comment: For some reason I don't get the same results as yours, and anyway your results is not what I was hoping for since the *pw10_0, pw50_* are NaN and they should be populated with values. Please look at my desired results in the question, thanks.

Comment: So it seems that my df was a bit weird. I did not read it from a file but it was created as part of the script and looked completely normal. Instead of keep working on this df, I saved it as excel file and read it again to pandas from the folder using `pd.read_excel`. The "new" df (that was read from the excel) behaves normally and the merge was successful simply by using `pd.merge(df_pw6,df_ex,on=['date','ID'])`. I have no idea why the df from the script showed this strange behavior.

Comment: @user88484 ah indeed sorry my bad; let me come back in a bit.

Comment: @user88484 are you saying using df from excel and merge using above command gave you desired outcome?

Comment: Yes, I got the desired result. Somehow, the same df behaves differently depends on how I read it.

Comment: @user88484, I have updated the answer. it was actually just a typo, I copied the wrong result from below. Now with update, following my example can achieve the desired outcome. I removed the `concat` though, we can still do it, but it is way too much effort required.